# How to access scrapy settings from item Pipeline

Tags: python, scrapy, settings, pipeline

How do I access the scrapy settings in settings.py from the item pipeline. The documentation mentions it can be accessed through the crawler in extensions, but I don't see how to access the crawler in the pipelines.

Answer (score 41):

> **UPDATE**  (2021-05-04)
> *Please note that this answer is now ~7 years old, so it's validity can no longer be ensured. In addition it is using Python2*

The way to access your Scrapy settings (as defined in `settings.py`) from within `your_spider.py` is simple. All other answers are way too complicated. The reason for this is the very poor maintenance of the Scrapy documentation, combined with many recent updates & changes. Neither in the "Settings" documentation "[How to access settings](http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/settings.html#how-to-access-settings)", nor in the ["Settings API"](http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/api.html#module-scrapy.settings) have they bothered giving any workable example. Here's an example, how to get your current **USER_AGENT** string.

Just add the following lines to `your_spider.py`:

```
# To get your settings from (settings.py):
from scrapy.utils.project import get_project_settings
...
class YourSpider(BaseSpider):
    ...
    def parse(self, response):
        ...
        settings = get_project_settings()
        print "Your USER_AGENT is:\n%s" % (settings.get('USER_AGENT'))
        ...
```

As you can see, there's no need to use `@classmethod` or re-define the `from_crawler()` or `__init__()` functions. Hope this helps.

**PS.** I'm still not sure why using `from scrapy.settings import Settings` doesn't work the same way, since it would be the more obvious choice of import?

Comment: Despite the documentation suggest the method used @avaleske I still prefer this way because it works and faster to understand.

Comment: This method **did not** recognize settings that were [overridden from the command line](http://doc.scrapy.org/en/0.24/topics/settings.html#command-line-options). Use @avaleske's answer if you want this functionality.

Comment: Also you won't get settings overriden by spider

Answer (score 31):

Ok, so the documentation at http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/extensions.html says that

> The main entry point for a Scrapy extension (this also includes
>   middlewares and pipelines) is the from_crawler class method which
>   receives a Crawler instance which is the main object controlling the
>   Scrapy crawler. Through that object you can access settings, signals,
>   stats, and also control the crawler behaviour, if your extension needs
>   to such thing.

So then you can have a function to get the settings.

```
@classmethod
def from_crawler(cls, crawler):
    settings = crawler.settings
    my_setting = settings.get("MY_SETTING")
    return cls(my_setting)
```

The crawler engine then calls the pipeline's init function with `my_setting`, like so:

```
def __init__(self, my_setting):
    self.my_setting = my_setting
```

And other functions can access it with `self.my_setting`, as expected.

**Alternatively**, in the `from_crawler()` function you can pass the `crawler.settings` object to `__init__()`, and then access settings from the pipeline as needed instead of pulling them all out in the constructor.

Comment: That sound awfully complicated. Isn't there a more easy way to do this, or perhaps a better explanation? Could you not use `from scrapy.settings import Settings`?

Comment: @user1147688 I'd use this method, because it conforms to the dependency-injection based internal API of scrapy. Your suggestion may work, but it doesn't look like there's any guarantee that it will continue to in the future, as internal APIs may be moved around.

Comment: @avaleske, this works awesome, however do you know how we can use this to set a setting? For example, in some other function, say I wanted to change one of the settings values, like `download_delay`. Can we do that?

Comment: This is very confusing.  Could someone explain what code goes into what file?

Comment: I get `(False, <twisted.python.failure.Failure builtins.AttributeError: 'FilesDownloadPipeline' object has no attribute 'crawler'>)` after I've added the above code in an item pipeline, `class FilesDownloadPipeline(FilesPipeline)`

Answer (score 24):

The correct answer is: it depends where in the pipeline you wish to access the settings.

avaleske has answered as if you wanted access to the settings outside of your pipelines `process_item` method but it's very likely this is where you'll want the setting and therefore there is a much easier way as the Spider instance itself gets passed in as an argument.

```
class PipelineX(object):

    def process_item(self, item, spider):
         wanted_setting = spider.settings.get('WANTED_SETTING')
```

Comment: Great answer. For my project it made more sense to put the logic into the `open_spider` method as I only use the value when the spider first loads.

Answer (score 3):

the project structure is quite flat, why not:

```
# pipeline.py
from myproject import settings
```

Comment: and then youre gonna change the `myproject` every time you start a new one

Comment: You won't get settings overriden by spider